# Pandoc gives "Not an editor command" in Vim

Tags: vim, pandoc

When I run `:%!pandoc --from=html --to=markdown | pandoc --from=markdown --to=html`, it works fine.

I am trying to add the following command in my .vimrc after watching [this vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/using-external-filter-commands-to-reformat-html/).

```
nnoremap <leader>gq :%!pandoc -f html -t markdown | pandoc -f markdown -t html<CR>
vnoremap <leader>gq :!pandoc -f html -t markdown | pandoc -f markdown -t html<CR>
```

However when I write `:w`, it give errors with "Not an editor command" as you can see in the image.

What am I missing here? How can I add the codes in my .vimrc?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `<bar>` or `\|` to separate commands in mappings

```
nnoremap <leader>gq :%!pandoc -f html -t markdown <bar> pandoc -f markdown -t html<CR>
vnoremap <leader>gq :!pandoc -f html -t markdown <bar> pandoc -f markdown -t html<CR>
```

In your map `|` is being used to separate the `nnoremap` command and the next command which is not what you want.

Take a look at `:h map_bar`